# How to set td width by jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a table which width is 100%. The table can have several cells. How can I set cell width by jquery. If i have 2 td I need to set them 50%, 50%.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `var colCount=0; $('tr:nth-child(1) td').each(function () {colCount++;
}); $("td").width=(100/colCount)+"%";`  This should work, but I didn't test it so if there are problems let me know.

Comment: Instead of this $("td").width=(100/colCount)+"%"; is needed to write
$(".entry-content td").width((100/colCount)+"%");

Comment: Answers go down there.

Comment: Was untested, not guaranteed to be a valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please go through the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width-value).

```
$('table td').width(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$("#td_id").attr('width', value);`